# Refresh current view after asynctask started in another activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity, android-asynctask, refresh

I have a situation where I have multiple activities that deal with a single global list of objects.

From activity A, I can start an asynctask which sends an HTTP Get request to retrieve an XML message then parses the XML file into a series of objects.

My aim is to be able to refresh all views, only if the underlying data structure changes.

This should ideally mean that I can launch activity A, call an asynctask, move onto activity B, C D etc, and when the asynctask completes (no matter what activity I am on) the current view should be updated.

I've looked into broadcast listeners but I am not sure I am on the right direction with this, would it be possible for somebody to explain if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using `AsyncTask` for this since you aren't finishing in the `Activity`. You probably want to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `AsyncTask` instances are dependent of the caller `Activity`, I think this is not the correct approach. In your case, as you need to recover the result within *any* `Activity`, I'd use an unbound `Service` so it might be accessed whenever you want, wherever you want.

You might also use a local `BroadcastReceiver` which would send a signal to all of your `Activity`s and, those registering the action that sent your `AsyncTask`/`Service`, would perform the necessary actions you may need. Be careful as if your `Activity` has not been started, obviously that `Activity` won't be able to process what you've sent since that receiver should be unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

Just post a runnable to the handler of the current Activity.

Your activities can implement a common interface, where a function "updateUI" or whatever exists, and that way your runnable can be one line, and be agnostic as to the current active instance.

As you probably know the postexecute part of the asynctask runs on the UI thread of the activity that launches it.  Since that activity may be dead, just post to the handler in the "doinbackground" part of the async task and keep postexecute blank.

```
interface Updateable{

public Handler getHandler();
public void updateUI();

}

From Async Thread

final Updateable curr_activity = ...
Handler handle = curr_activity.getHandler();


    handle.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            curr_activity.updateUI();

        }
    });
```